# What am I doing wrong with my ViewController Subview Delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm trying to setup a delegate to handle swipe actions on a subview that's based on a Tinder type example (https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards).

I load my background view:

SwipeController.h

```
#import "DraggableView.h"

@interface SwipeViewController : UIViewController <DraggableViewDelegate>

//methods called in DraggableView
-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;

@end
```

SwipeViewController.m

```
    ....
                     // since we have all the data, lets show some cards
                     DraggableViewBackground *draggableBackground = [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
                     [draggableBackground setupViewWithImages:_results];                 
                     [self.view addSubview:draggableBackground];
    ....
-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped up");
}

-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped Left");
}

-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped Right");
}
...
```

DragableBackground.m

```
...
    // assign the delegate
    SwipeViewController *swipeViewController = [[SwipeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    draggableView.delegate = swipeViewController;

    return draggableView;
...
```

and finally my DragableView, which is what I'm trying to Delegate from the SwipeController:

```
@protocol DraggableViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;

@end

@interface DraggableView : UIView

@property (weak) id <DraggableViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting that you are not satisfied with?  If there's any way to be a bit more explicit with the problem, it will help with diagnosing it.

Comment: The cardSwipedUp, cardSwipedLeft, and cardSwipeRight is not being fired in the SwitchController Delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The `SwipeViewController` that you are setting as the delegate inside `DraggableViewBackground.m` is a different instance that you are creating locally and that gets deallocated immediately after that method returns.

You need to add some way for the `SwipeViewController` to tell the `DraggableViewBackground` that it wants to be the `DraggableView`'s delegate.  You could add a `setViewDelegate:` method to your `DraggableViewBackground` and have it call `setDelegate:` on the `DraggableView`s, then you can do `[draggableBackground setViewDelegate:self]` in the `SwipeViewController` after you create `draggableBackground` and `[draggableView setDelegate:self.viewDelegate]` in `DraggableViewBackground` when it creates a new `DraggableView`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... So for the next poor soul..

In my example the SwipeViewController is the parent to the DraggableViewBACKGROUND View, and that view is the parent to the DraggableView.. Think of it like passing down the responsibility to it's parent delegate at each step of the view (Card > Card Background > Swipe Controller). So for my working example, I needed DraggableViewBACKGROUND to delegate some of DraggableView, and I needed SwipeViewController to delegate some of DraggableViewBACKGROUND.

To make that happen,

```
#import "DraggableViewBackground.h"

@interface SwipeViewController : UIViewController <DraggableViewBackgroundDelegate>

//methods called in DraggableViewBACKGROUND
-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;

@end
```

DraggableViewBACKGROUND then got

```
@protocol DraggableViewBackgroundDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;

@end


@interface DraggableViewBackground : UIView <DraggableViewDelegate>

@property (weak) id <DraggableViewBackgroundDelegate> delegate;

//methods called in DraggableView
-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;
```

and the DraggableView got

```
@protocol DraggableViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;

@end

@interface DraggableView : UIView

@property (weak) id <DraggableViewDelegate> delegate;
```

So in each delegate I could perform the action needed and then call it's parent delegate. DraggableViewBACKGROUND delegate handler for action, which would be called the same way from the DraggableView..

```
-(void)cardSwipedUp:(UIView *)card;
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped up");
    [delegate cardSwipedUp:self];
}
```

That did the trick for me, as the DraggableViewBACKGROUND would handle popping elements off the card array and collecting other data that was not accessible to the DraggableView object, or the SwipeViewController. Hope that helps someone else!